# React native axios call throws 403 but postman correctly outputs the data

Tags: react-native, redux, axios

I'm working on a RN app, which has redux in it. Now I can login with the help of jwt but when Im trying the to get the data from my other component its giving me 403 error. Please find below the relevant code.

Here is my reducer:

```
 const initState = {
        isLoadingCollegeDashList : false,
        collegeDashList:{},
        collegeDashListFail:false
    }
    const collegeReducer = ( state = initState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case 'IS_LOADING_COLLEGE_DASH_LIST' : 
            return{
                ...state,
                isLoadingCollegeDashList: true,
                collegeDashList : false
            }
            case 'COLLEGE_DASH_LIST' : 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoadingCollegeDashList : false,
                collegeDashList : true,
                userData : action.userData
            }
            case  'COLLEGE_DASH_LIST_FAIL' : 
            return{
                ...state,
                isLoadingCollegeDashList:false,
                collegeDashList: false,
                collegeDashListFail: action.error
            }
            default : 
            return state 
        }
    }
and here's my action that's making get request

export const populateCollege = (token) => {
    const headers = {
        'api-secret' : ...secret...,
        'authorization':...authToken...,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

      }
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(isLoadingCollegeDashList(true));
      return axios.get( '...api/api/...', {
      },{
          headers:headers,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.status < 300){
          dispatch(isLoadingCollegeDashList(false))
          dispatch(collegeDashList(response))
          console.log(response);
        }
        else{
          response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
            console.log("responseJSON",responseJSON);
            dispatch(isLoadingCollegeDashList(false))
            dispatch(collegeDashListFail(responseJSON.message))
          })
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error",error);
        dispatch(isLoadingCollegeDashList(false))
        dispatch(collegeDashListFail(error))

      })
    }
  }

export const isLoadingCollegeDashList = (bool) => {
    return{
      type:'IS_LOADING_COLLEGE_DASH_LIST',
      isLoadingCollegeDashList:bool
    }
  }

  export const collegeDashList = (userData) => {
    return{
      type:'COLLEGE_DASH_LIST',
      userData
    }
  }

  export const collegeDashListFail = (error) => {
    return{
      type:'COLLEGE_DASH_LIST_FAIL',
      error
    }
  }
```

here's action that im calling if you want to check it

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  populateCollege : (token) => dispatch(actions.populateCollege({token}))
});
```

PS I've for now stored token in the state of one hence passing the token from this dispatch itself.

Let me know if you need any clarification / more information then do let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the authorisation schema before your token. The schema can be like Basic, Bearer or any other value based on your authorisation details. (eg. Authorization: Bearer TOKEN).
Also, try to reuse your auth headers while creating the axios instance so you won't need to inject them on every call.